# Bootstrap 4 inline form increase input width and keep the form inline on xs widths

Tags: bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I searched a lot for this, and I couldn't find the answer

I use **bootstrap 4** and I have the following code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<form class="form-inline text-xs-center">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Go</button>
</form>
```

I have 2 problems at diffirent **resolutions**.

**(1)** At **sm or larger resolutions**, the result is as follows:

[click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXhDf.png)

The input and the button are **inline**, with proper **padding** between them, and are well **centered**.  how can I **increase the width** of this inline input, with preserving the padding and the center alignment (of both controls together)?

**(2)** At **xs resoltion**, the result is as follows: (expand snippet, run it, and resize browser)

[click fo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umS9v.png)

I **lost the inline** state of the form, how can keep the form inline at this resolution?

thanks in advance

Comment: does your button need to be inside the form-group element/class?

Comment: @ganders thank you for reply, it is not inside form-group, it is inside a form with the class `form-inline`. Actually I couldn't figure out a solution, so I reverted to [input groups](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/input-group/), where the text input stacked to the button

Answer (score 2):

Revisiting this question with the latest **Bootstrap 4.0.0**.

Now that flexbox is in Bootstrap 4, this can be easily done using the auto-layout columns which shrink to fit width (`col-auto`), or grow to fill width (`col`).

https://www.codeply.com/go/4XzeaA9eGl

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="row text-center">
        <div class="col pr-1">
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto px-0">
            <button type="submit" class="col-auto btn btn-primary"> Go </button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks & +1 for your kind reply, I'm way too far from remembering the problem